# Is Apple's MacBook Pro RAM simply rebranded?

Tags: memory, macbook-pro

Apple typically charges a markup for its own MacBook Pro RAM - often twice (or more) the price of Crucial RAM.

Is Apple RAM actually better, or is it just a rebrand of another manufacturer's memory?

Comment: This question was asked and answered over at [apple.stackexchange.com](http://apple.stackexchange.com): [Apple-Certified RAM?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/apple-certified-ram/). Summary: yes, there is one real, significant difference between Apple RAM and non-Apple RAM.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a rebrand, and quite possibly came from Crucial. :)  This is a common revenue-enhancing stunt practiced by many computer makers (although Dell has reportedly dropped it of late); Apple is banking on people being willing to pay extra to not have to worry about installing it, phantom "compatibility" issues, etc.

Comment: Chances are it varies as well. It may be Crucial one month and another brand the next, depending on availability at the Apple warehouses, but it will always be a rebrand.